# [Laravel]Failed to access a css file

Tags: css, laravel, amazon-ec2

I created web page using blade so I checked if it works on brower, though it failed to access a css file.
I checked a brower developer and found a error message says 'Failed to load resource: net::ERROR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT'.

Actually, I created this page on cloud9 and it seemed to reflect a css correctly.
When I move this program to another ec2 server, this error is happened.
It seems that css is in correct location( https://(IP address)/css/OO.css).

- In blade,
  I wrote ＜link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/OO.css', true) }}"＞ to refer a css.
- As for css location,
  public/css/〇〇.css
- permissons, I execute following commands.
  sudo chmod -R 777 ./storage
  sudo chmod -R 777 ./bootstrap/cache
  sudo chmod -R 777 ./public/css
- In .env, I add settings below
  ASSET_URL=https://(IP address)/public

I would like to investigate why it occurs, though I dont know what to do.
I'm suffering to solve it for a while, so any advices or comments are helpful.

Any advices or comments are helpful.

Comment: This is too broad. There can be many causes to this. I would suggest you open your browser developer console and check the errors to see if the URL that you are trying to load is correctly set-up to be served by your webserver and perhaps share more information like webserver configuration etc

Comment: Actually ,The  error message 'Failed to load resource: net::ERROR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT'. is found on brower developer and it seems that css is in correct location( https://(IP address)/css/OO.css). In blade, I wrote <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/OO.css') }}"> to refer a css.

Comment: Is that IP address accessible over the internet (on the http/https ports) based on security rules? Can you provide more information on your setup e.g. is this behind a load balancer? what is your webserver vhost configuration

Comment: `index.php` -- starting of the Laravel Application is exist in the `/public` folder?

Comment: If Yes, then add `ASSET_URL` in your `.env` as well as in `config/app.php` file, then use `{{ asset( YOUR ASSET PATH ) }}`

Comment: It seems that html is loaded properly, so I guess its not about http/https ports or security rules.  Just I connected to ec2 directly without any load balanc,  as for vhost setting, I editted /etc/httpd/conf/httd.conf. 
＜VirtualHost *:80＞
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/〇〇/public
ServerName (MyServerName)
＜Directory /var/www/html/〇〇/public＞
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
＜/Directory＞
＜/VirtualHost＞

Answer (score 0):

have you check the css file permissions? i got this issue before, after giving my css file permission to 777 (-rwxrwxrwx) the css file is readable again

Comment: I execute following commands to add permissions though faced same issue.

[ec2-user@ ]$ sudo chmod -R 777 ./storage
[ec2-user@ ]$ chmod -R 777 ./bootstrap/cache
[ec2-user@ ]$ chmod -R 777 ./public/css
[ec2-user@ ]$ php artisan view:clear

Are there another factors to cause this issue?

Comment: is your ip has SSL? because from your answer above the link on error was https://(IP address)/public, because too many can cause this error i think one can cause this was Https

Answer (score 0):

It's mostly due to the permission issue on ec2 servers, For Laravel this is what we run in the ec2 server command line after the first deployment to make sure permissions are set properly.

Login into your EC2 server using SSH and then run following commands to fix the permissions:

sudo chmod 777 -R /var/www/html/public/css
sudo chmod 777 -R /var/www/html/bootstrap/cache
sudo chmod 777 -R /var/www/html/storage

Note: Your Laravel install location might be different so please correct the path according to that.

Comment: I put permissions you mentions above though I have not resolved yet. Do you have any another ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added `ASSET_URL` in your `config/app.php` and `.env` file

```php
// in your config/app.php file

'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost'),

'asset_url' => env('ASSET_URL'),
```

```
ASSET_URL=http://localhost/public
```

and then try `asset()` for link css

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('YOUR CSS PATH') }}" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I checked config/app.php and found following code.

'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost'),
'asset_url' => env('ASSET_URL'),

So I add ASSET URL setting below in .env file.
ASSET_URL=https://(IP address)/public

Though it doesnt work yet, actually.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for giving many advices.

The reason why I faced this issue is

In blade
＜link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/OO.css', true) }}"＞

Just I fixed it to
＜link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/OO.css') }}"＞

I dont have to use 'https'.